# Content database does not exist restoring a site collection

Tags: backup, stsadm, restore

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal template. I am using the following backup and restore process to backup from site collection http://machine1 to site collection http://machine2/sites/site2. I want to know whether my backup and restore process is correct? (both source and destination are site collections.)

Another question is, I am confused in step 2, if I do not create a new content database from Central Administration, and in step 3, the restore command will output error says content database not exists? why?

Step 1: (from source machine1) backup stsadm.exe -o backup -url http://machine1 -filename e:\backup.dat

Step 2: (from destination machine2) create a site collection http://machine2/sites/site2 and create a new content database

Step 3: (from destination machine2) stsadm.exe -o restore -url http://machine2/sites/site2 -filename e:\backup.dat -overwrite

Answer (score 3):

In your example you are backing up the root site collection of machine1 and restoring it under a managed path on machine2.  You may want to make those consistent.

Emad is correct about step #2, as long as the application is setup on the server you will not need to create a content db.

One last tip, make sure that you have any customizations or solutions installed.  If supporting solutions are not installed you will start seeing a number of errors until all of that is worked out.

Comment: "the application is setup on the server" -- currently I have an web application which is setup at http://machine2, and it has its root site collection at http://machine2. And I am restoring another root site collection from machine1 to http://mahcine2/sites/site2. In this scenario, I am wondering what do you mean "the application is setup on the server"? Any additional settings for me?

Comment: I have this confusion because if I do not create the content db, there will be error message from stsadm -o restore says content db not exists.

Comment: If there is already a root site collection at http://machine2 then you do have the iis web app created/extended already and there is a content db already in place.

Comment: But when I use command "stsadm.exe -o restore -url http://machine2/sites/site2 -filename e:\backup.dat -overwrite" without creating a content database, there will be error message no content database created. After create a content database it is working correctly. Any ideas why? I am using SQL Server 2005 Express which is shipped with SharePoint Server 2007, not sure whether it is a restriction of SQL Server Express?

Comment: Before I create the restore command, I create a web application at http://machine2 and create a site collection (publishing portal) at http://machine2 as well.

Comment: SQL Server Express shouldn't be a factor here.  The only thing I can think of is if the content db is already maxed out or not in a "Offline" state.  If it is set to "Offline" no new site collections can be created into it.

Comment: How to check -- "the content db is already maxed out or not in a "Offline" state"?

Comment: Go to Central Administration, Application Management, Content Databases.  It will list out all of the content databases for a given application.  Please check to make sure you are looking at the application you want, and change the selector in the upper right if applicable.

Comment: Could you help to descibe what exactly means maxed out and "Offline" state? I think maxed out you mean out of quota? And "Offline" you mean the SQL Server service process is not running? But I am not sure. Please help to describe to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: I can't find a reference that goes into the details now, but Offline just means that no additional sites can be created in that database.  The sites are still available for updates.  It is a SharePoint configuration setting and does not impact the underlying database at all.  This value can be manually set, or it can be done automatically when the max number of site collections number is reached.  This is set on the same page where the content database info is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I think step 2 is not needed. You can restore directly to a web application (You must make sure that a web application on the destination server exists). No need to create a site collection whose database will be overwritten by the restore action anyway.

Comment: "You can restore directly to a web application" -- currently I have an web application which is setup at machine2, and it has its root site collection at machine2. And I am restoring another root site collection from machine1 to http://machine2/sites/site2. In this scenario, I am wondering what do you mean "You must make sure that a web application on the destination server exists"? Any additional settings for me?